# recycler must not be null in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have recycler where I show list of user previous orders but for new users this list is empty therefore I get following error, **recycler must not be null** I've tried to replace recycler with static image for this case scenario but my app crashes.

I have 2 guesses why this crash happening but how to fix it, I'm not sure

1. I've placed my visibility code in wrong place
2. I didn't get my recycler id correctly

#### Code

`Fragment XML`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".OrdersFragment">
    
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/ordersList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/order"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:text="@string/orders" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|top"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="#3F51B5"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/incomingOrder"
        android:textColor="#CDDC39" />

    <!-- Replacement image incase of empty list -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/emptyOrders"
        android:src="@drawable/empt" />

</FrameLayout>
```

`Fragment`

```
class OrdersFragment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {

    var navController: NavController? = null
    private lateinit var emptyImage: ImageView

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_orders, container, false)
        callOrdersAPI()
        emptyImage = root.findViewById(R.id.empty) as ImageView
        return root
    }

    fun callOrdersAPI() {
        var session = SessionManager(context)
        session.checkLogin()
        var user = session.getUserDetails()
        var uId: String? = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_ID)
        var token: String? = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN)
        val tokenFull = "Bearer $token"

        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
        val url = "https://example.com/api/orders"

        val stringReq : StringRequest =
            object : StringRequest(Method.GET, url,
                Response.Listener { response ->
                    // response
                    val list: ArrayList<Data> = ArrayList()
                    getOrders(response, list)

                    recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
                    // trying to set visibility
                    if (list.size == 0) {
                        emptyImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
                        recycler.setVisibility(View.GONE)
                    } else {
                        emptyImage.setVisibility(View.GONE)
                        recycler.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
                        recycler.adapter = OrdersAdapter(list)
                    }
                },
                Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                    Toast.makeText(context, error.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                }
            ){
                override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
                    val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                    headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
                    headers["Authorization"] = tokenFull
                    return headers
                }
            }
        queue.add(stringReq)
    }

    fun getOrders(response: String, list: ArrayList<Data>) {
        var jsonObject = JSONObject(response)
        val jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data")

        for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
            val jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
            var listingObject = Data(
                jsonObject1.getInt("accepted"),
                jsonObject1.getString("amount"),
                jsonObject1.getString("created_at"),
                jsonObject1.getString("id"),
                jsonObject1.getString("payment"),
                jsonObject1.getString("payment_id"),
                jsonObject1.getString("payment_method"),
                jsonObject1.getString("total"),
                jsonObject1.getString("transport"),
                jsonObject1.getString("weight"),
                jsonObject1.get("laundry") as Laundry,
                jsonObject1.get("customer") as Customer,
                jsonObject1.get("driver") as Driver,
                jsonObject1.get("progresses") as Progresses,
                jsonObject1.get("services") as Servic
            )
            list.add(listingObject)
        }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
        view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.back).setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when(v!!.id) {
            R.id.back -> navController!!.navigate(R.id.action_ordersFragment_to_incomingOrderFragment)
        }
    }
}
```

`Adapter`

```
class OrdersAdapter(private var orderList: ArrayList<Data>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<OrdersAdapter.OrderViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): OrderViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.orders_item, parent, false)

        return OrderViewHolder(itemView)
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: OrderViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = orderList[position]
        holder.textView.text = currentItem.amount
        // todo...
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = orderList.size

    class OrderViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val textView: TextView = itemView.amount
        // todo...
    }
}
```

## Update

As requested my `Logcat`

```
1612282056.833 15860-15860/com.my.app E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
1612282056.926 15860-15860/com.my.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.my.app, PID: 15860
    java.lang.NullPointerException: recycler must not be null
        at com.my.app.OrdersFragment$callOrdersAPI$stringReq$2.onResponse(OrdersFragment.kt:59) <-- //recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        at com.my.app.OrdersFragment$callOrdersAPI$stringReq$2.onResponse(OrdersFragment.kt:53) <-- //object : StringRequest(Method.GET, url,
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:82)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:29)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7561)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995)
```

Comment: can you post your crash logcat?

Comment: and where in your code set the `recycler` variable? (I don't see if it's even declared)

Comment: it's coming from here `import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager` I do not define it elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add your build app build.gradle

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

then your fragment add ordersList( your RecyclerView id). after that it will ask imports layout include it.

```
               if (list.size == 0) {
                    emptyImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
                    ordersList.setVisibility(View.GONE)
                } else {
                    emptyImage.setVisibility(View.GONE)
                    recycler.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
                    ordersList.adapter = OrdersAdapter(list)
                }
```

it will work

Comment: Exactly what I just realized was `recycler` supposed to be id of my recycler which is `ordersList`

Comment: This is exactly why `kotlin-android-extensions` was deprecated.